# Does Golang support variadic function?

Tags: go

I wonder if there a way where I can define a function for unknown number of variables in Go.

Something like this

```
func Add(num1... int) int {
    return args
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    fmt.Println(Add(1, 3, 4, 5,))
}
```

I want to generalize the function `Add` for any number of inputs.

Comment: how is this related to Ruby?

Comment: Everything is related to Ruby.

Comment: Ruby does something like this puts long_string[-3..-1]

Answer (score 105, accepted):

You've pretty much got it, from what I can tell, but the syntax is `...int`. See [the spec](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters):

> Given the function and call
>
> ```
> func Greeting(prefix string, who ...string)
> Greeting("hello:", "Joe", "Anna", "Eileen")
> ```
>
> within Greeting, `who` will have the value `[]string{"Joe", "Anna", "Eileen"}`

Comment: TL;DR; varargs are implicitly converted into a slice. If you want varargs of arbitrary type, use ...interface{}

Comment: @fuz when using `...interface{}` in the function declaration, how would you call it with a single variable?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. If anyone else has the problem here's how I did it: https://play.golang.org/p/PvqevBGAAv

Answer (score 7):

While using the variadic parameters, you need to use loop in the datatype inside your function.

```
func Add(nums... int) int {
    total := 0
    for _, v := range nums {
        total += v
    }
    return total  
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    fmt.Println(Add(1, 3, 4, 5,))
}
```

Answer (score 3):

### Golang have a very simple variadic function declaration

Variadic functions can be called with any number of trailing arguments. For example, `fmt.Println` is a common variadic function.

Here’s a function that will take an arbitrary number of `int`'s as arguments.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func sum(nums ...int) {
    fmt.Println(nums)
    for _, num := range nums {
        fmt.Print(num)
    }
}

func main() {
    sum(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)
}
```

Output of the above program:

> [1 2 3 4 5 6]
>
> 1 2 3 4 5 6